# Exception thrown: read access violation. **thunkData** was 0x13E6CC3

Tags: c++, pointers, portable-executable

I am facing an issue with a read/write access violation. Could someone please help me? I've read many forums to find a solution, but it didn't work out.

Here is the function from my code.

```
void configureLoaderIMP(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* loaderSecHeader, BYTE* loaderBaseAddress) {
    DWORD offsetIMP = 0;
    getLoaderIMP(NULL, &offsetIMP);
    DWORD rvaBaseAddress = loaderSecHeader->VirtualAddress + offsetIMP;
    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR* imageImpDescriptor = (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*)(loaderBaseAddress + offsetIMP);
    while (imageImpDescriptor->Name != 0) {
        if (imageImpDescriptor->OriginalFirstThunk != 0) {
            imageImpDescriptor->OriginalFirstThunk += rvaBaseAddress;
        }
        imageImpDescriptor->Name += rvaBaseAddress;
        IMAGE_THUNK_DATA* thunkData = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA*)(loaderBaseAddress + offsetIMP + imageImpDescriptor->FirstThunk);
        imageImpDescriptor->FirstThunk += rvaBaseAddress;
        while (thunkData->u1.AddressOfData != 0) {
            thunkData->u1.AddressOfData += rvaBaseAddress;
            ++thunkData;
        }
        ++imageImpDescriptor;
    }
}
```

The issue appears in the "while" block `while (thunkData->u1.AddressOfData != 0)..`. The error message says "Exception thrown: read access violation. **thunkData** was 0x13E6CC3"

I tried to make the 'thunkData' variable global, allocate memory for it through VirtualAlloc, nothing worked. The main purpose of my program is to create a PE packer. Please don't judge very harshly if the code (this function) looks very bad.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's a lot of pointers and pointer arithmetic. One of them are clearly wrong. You need to *debug* your program, not only this little function.